# Why are these methods public?

Tags: javascript, public-method

My javascript looks like the following.  I don't understand why these methods are all public though?

```
Something.RegisterNamespace("One.ABC");

    (function(ABC) {

      ABC.SayHello = function() {
             alert('hello');

      };

    })(One.ABC);
```

So now I can do:

```
One.ABC.SayHello();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the `SayHello` function into the object being passed in, which is `One.ABC`.  What else are you expecting?  If you want a private function, define it inside your anonymous function (`var SayHello = function(){...}`) without adding it to the object.  Not sure what you're trying to accomplish...

**EDIT**:

Here's how I would rewrite your code to do what I think you want:

```
One = {};
One.ABC = {};

(function(ABC) {
    var PrivateHello = function(){
        alert('hello');
    };
    ABC.PublicHello = function() {
        PrivateHello();
    };
})(One.ABC);

One.ABC.PublicHello(); // alerts 'hello'
One.ABC.PrivateHello(); // error 'One.ABC.PrivateHello is not a function'
```

Comment: I guess I don't totally grasp closures then :(

Comment: If you really want to learn closures (and JS in general) do yourself a favor and pick up David Flanagan's book: http://www.amazon.com/JavaScript-Definitive-Guide-Activate-Pages/dp/0596805527/

Answer (score 2):

The only effective way to have private methods is by using a closure.

```
function MyClass() {
    var privateMethod = function() {
        return 0;
    };

    this.publicMethod = function() {
        return privateMethod();
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code can also be written as:

```
var One = {
      ABC:{
       SayHello: function() {
         alert('hello');
       }
      }
};
One.ABC.SayHello(); //=> hello
```

This variable definition creates a (pseudo) namespace `One` (actually, an Object in the global namespace). The first property of `One` is `ABC`. `ABC` is an Object too and has one property, the public method`SayHello`.
If you wanted `SayHello` to be private, this could be a way to do it:

```
var Two = {
    ABC: ( function(){
        // SayHello is a private function within this
        // anonymous function 
        // it can only be accessed by a public method 
        // you create (here it's the method Hi)
        function SayHello() {
          alert('hello from Two.ABC');
        }
        return {
                SayHello: function(){alert('you are not allowed to say Hello!');},
                Hi: SayHello
               };
        } )()
    }
    Two.ABC.SayHello(); //=> you are not allowed to say Hello!
    Two.ABC.Hi(); //=> hello from Two.ABC
```

Now `Two.ABC` is an object too, but it is created using an anonymous constructor function  instantiated on creation (a singleton pattern I think it's called). Within that constructor `SayHello` is now a private (not publicly accessible) function. You'll have to assign some public method to access `SayHello` (here: `Two.ABC.Hi`), otherwise it will be completely hidden. In this example, because `SayHello` is defined within the anonymous function scope, it is accessible for the methods that anonymous function returns, which in turn are accessible to the parent scopes (ABC and TWo). In other words, the function `SayHello` is *enclosed* by the methods the singleton returns.

Answer (score 0):

I hope the function's name and the Name space's name are same, so those can be referred as public

Answer (score 0):

RegisterNamespace is not standard JS. But that looks like it is creating an object "One" with a property of "ABC"

The anonymous function is binding its inner function to the object "One" via the property "ABC"

So you end up with:

```
var One = {"ABC" : { "SayHello" : function(){alert('hello')}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

all properties/objects of an object are public. the code sample you've posted is equivalent to

```
Something.RegisterNamespace("One.ABC");
One.ABC.SayHello = function() { alert('hello'); };
```

here, you're defining the property `SayHello` to be a function that executes the alert statement when called.

edit: perhaps you're being thrown off by the structure of the code? this section

```
(function(ABC) {
  ABC.SayHello = function() {
         alert('hello');

  };

})(One.ABC);
```

is equivalent to

```
function addHello(pObject) {
    pObject.SayHello = function() {
        alert('hello');
    };
}

addHello(One.ABC);
```

the only difference is that in your example, the function is being defined inline and then run immediately.

```
(...)(parameters);
```

defining it inline just make the function available for one-off use, where in my example you could use the same function to define a `SayHello` method for many objects.